# AWS Windows 10 Error 0x80070780: The file cannot be accessed by the system

Tags: amazon-web-services, log-files, windows-10, files, corruption

We have log files stored on one of our AWS machines, however, a significant amount of the log files have been corrupted without any clearly apparent reason.

When trying to open/read/write/rename/delete the files, we are shown a windows error `Error 0x80070780: The file cannot be accessed by the system` and we can't seem to find the source of the error.

To ensure that our code was not responsible for the corruption, I found healthy copies (*they are present on a different machine from which they are sent over to this machine*) of the corrupted log files and sent it over to the same directory as the corrupted files. The files I sent over were not corrupted after the transfer.

One of the possible culprits for this error is having permission issues, but I dont think that this is the reason for the corrupted files as we can access other files in this folder, and our user account has admin privileges.

*The "corrupted" files have an "X" on the icon, while the "healthy" files do not*: [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UtIK.png)

Some other things I noticed that were abnormal:

- *The `total size` of the healthy files is equal to the size of the hard drive; however, the `total size` of the "corrupted" files is undefined:* [total size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbEJK.png)
- *The `size on disk` of the "corrupted" files is 0:* [size on disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZC1O.png)

We also ran `chkdsk` to make sure that there were no "bad sectors" on the hard drive, but `chkdsk` also returned with no errors.

Has anyone run into any issues like this on AWS? What could cause an issue such a this and how can we avoid having this issue show up again in the future?

Comment: I can't help you with why, but if you want to back up files I would put them into S3 which is cheaper, more durable and generally more reliable than EBS attached to a Windows instance. A quick Google search suggests that error refers to a permissions problem.